# QTextDocument print to pdf and unicode

Tags: windows, qt, pdf

I try to print pdf file from QTextDocument. Content of document is set by setHtml(). 
Simplified example:

```
QTextDocument document;
document.setHtml("<h1>My html \304\205</h1>"); // Octal encoded ą

QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);

printer.setOutputFileName("cert.pdf");
document.print(&printer);
```

It does not work as expected on windows (msvc). I get pdf file with "?" in place of most polish characters. It works on ubuntu.

On windows It makes pdf with tahoma font embedded subset. How to force QPrinter or QPrintEngine to embed more characters from this (or any other) font?

Comment: That `setHtml` call is *extremely* suspicious. Please create a QString explicitely and dump it using qDebug(), before passing it to `setHtml`.

Comment: Dumping this text to qDebug() gives me same result in console(question marks in polish letters).
This octal encoding is suspicious? I took it from uic generated files and it works when I set widget text from code.

Comment: It is because the `const char *` -> `QString` conversion might not do what you want (especially on Qt 4). Are you using it? Does it make a difference to use QString::fromUtf8 instead? How about using the corresponding HTML-escape instead?

Comment: You're right. Thank you pepe. Both fromUtf8, tr(), and html escape sequence work.

Answer (score 1):

As pepe suggested in comments. I needed to wrap this string one of:

- QString::fromUtf8
- tr() (in case of joining translated parts)
- Use html escape sequence (ex. &#261 for ę)

My original html in program was build from tr() parts, but I forgot to octal escape some of them. (which worked on gcc, not on msvc, even with utf-8 with BOM)